# Send data from Android project to lib class - same object type

Tags: java, android

I have some data I get from a database that are type of `Item` ( Item is a class in my Project and serves as a Model ) and I store them to an ArrayList before I send them to a class in my library.

In my library I have the exact same `Item` class serving as model but ofcourse it's a different package.
So when I try to pass the data I have this :

```
getDataFromProject(ArrayList<com.project.Item>)
```

when it expects to be *com.library.Item*. I thought casting  the ArrayList before use it should work but it does not. 
Is there a "fast track" way I can achieve that or I should reconfigure my project so that I will have only one Item type ?